# font awesome ie9 https

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

This has been asked several times but none of the solutions found have helped. We are using font awesome over https (not sure it makes a difference) and the icons in IE9 show up as squares. This happens only on ie9.

Anyone had this issue before or have ideas?

Thank-you

Comment: When you say only on IE9, do you mean it works on Firefox, Chrome and other versions of IE?

Comment: See if this helps you: Best Practices for Serving Webfonts to IE9
http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems

Comment: That is correct VictorySaber, works in all except IE9. I will try that  link thank-you.

Comment: I've had the same issue, seems like [ICONIC](http://iconion.com/posts/how-to-convert-font-awesome-to-png-icons-k.html) is a very good solution for it

Answer (score 0):

This happens in IE only with https.

Remove any HTTP headers from the fontawesome relevant files that prevent caching, e.g.

```
Expires -1
Pragma: no-cache
```

After removing the cache control for these files you should see your icons. After reloading your page all the relevant fontawesome files should show HTTP code 304, i.e. the file comes from the browsers cache.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Check cache-invalidating headers in HTTP responses
because under https, 
Internet Explorer (up to IE11) seems to not load fonts nor vector icons if 
cache or store invalidating instructions are set in HTTP header :

For example, spring-boot generates the following headers, as a result, icons are not shown under https:

Cache-Control :"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"

and

pragma: "no-cache"

The solution is to hide those headers to the browser.

I used nginx as a proxy, adding the folowing commands the https proxied location:

proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
  proxy_hide_header Pragma;

See here for details with nginx.

Using apache httpd, the syntax is here